# Using Updatepanel to update html content of DIV element

Tags: html, asp.net, model-view-controller, updatepanel

I have aspx page which has 6 div panels with various real time information. Page receive this information from product API.  I would like to update only 2 panels in real time and other panel in some time like every 5 min 2 and every 10 min other 2. How can I achieve this functionality using asp.net or MVC.

Comment: If you want to update DOM with real time data then you should look into signalR.

Comment: I believe signalR is for events pushing to client. In this case I need request to API to get real time data. API does not push events or data. Currently I am refreshing the page and facing an issue with this. I suspect as I pull all information together it is causing issue. So I am looking for updating panels at different time interval.